# SQL - How do I SELECT additional parameters in an SQL Query with a DECLARE statement

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, coalesce, declare

I am using the output of this SQL in Crystal Reports. I have created a stored procedure as I have a `DECLARE` statement within the query.

I need to - `SELECT PP.PLPLANID` - as a parameter, as I have `DECLARE` in my query it seems to prevent me from selecting additional parameters. What do I need to do?

This is what I have so far - it is creating one row and column as I need, but I now need to add additional columns such as `PP.PLPLANID` etc.

```
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MultiZoneOverlays VARCHAR (2000)

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @MultiZoneOverlays = COALESCE(@MultiZoneOverlays +', ', '') + Z.NAME
    FROM PLPLAN PP
    JOIN PLPLANPARCEL PLP ON PP.PLPLANID = PLP.PLPLANID
    JOIN PARCEL P ON PLP.PARCELID = P.PARCELID
    JOIN PLPLANZONE PLZ ON PP.PLPLANID = PLZ.PLPLANID
    JOIN ZONE Z ON PLZ.ZONEID = Z.ZONEID
    WHERE "PP"."PLPLANID" = @PLPLANID
      AND PLP.Main = '1'
      AND PLZ.MAIN = '0'

    SELECT @MultiZoneOverlays AS MultiZoneOverlaysList
END
```

Comment: For a query you either assign all columns to variables or not - you can't mix and match. So if you want to select an additional column you need to assign it to another variable. However why do you need to assign the results of the query to variables and then select them? Why not just select the values directly in the first place?

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using? With SQL Server (starting with 2017) you can use `STRING_AGG()`

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: I'm using SQL not Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.5388.0

Comment: I am using the result from this query in Crystal Reports as a sub report - so I need the PLPLANID to link the sub report to the main report.  I need to create 3 of these DECLARE statements for 3 different parameters for the one Crystal Report and will need to link all of these to the main report.  Is there another way to link?  Also, I am new to this, so I am not great with the terminology - sorry in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not saying it's the best way, but, for the sake of learning, to add more variables following the model in your current procedure, you can do this:

```
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MultiZoneOverlays VARCHAR (2000)
    , @Variable2 varchar(2000)
    , @Variable3 varchar(2000)

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @MultiZoneOverlays = COALESCE(@MultiZoneOverlays +', ', '') + Z.NAME
    , @Variable2 = Column2
    , @Variable3 = Column3
    FROM PLPLAN PP
    JOIN PLPLANPARCEL PLP ON PP.PLPLANID = PLP.PLPLANID
    JOIN PARCEL P ON PLP.PARCELID = P.PARCELID
    JOIN PLPLANZONE PLZ ON PP.PLPLANID = PLZ.PLPLANID
    JOIN ZONE Z ON PLZ.ZONEID = Z.ZONEID
    WHERE "PP"."PLPLANID" = @PLPLANID
      AND PLP.Main = '1'
      AND PLZ.MAIN = '0'

    SELECT @MultiZoneOverlays AS MultiZoneOverlaysList
    ,      @Variable2 AS Var2
    ,      @Variable3 AS Var3
END
```